# Reuse the internal buffer of std::function when assigning function-object

Tags: c++, std-function

I want to reuse the internal buffer of `std::function<T>`, if the newly assigned function object is of the same type as the already stored one. Is the following well defined, and is it worth it?

Here, `f` is the `std::function` value, and `x` is the function object to be assigned to it.

```
auto fast_assign = [](auto &f, auto x) { 
   using X = decltype(x); 
   if(auto *t = f.template target<X>()) { 
      t->~X(); 
      new ((void*)t) X(std::move(x)); 
   } else 
      f = std::move(x); 
}
```

I intend to use it like this

```
fast_assign(someStdFn, somethingThatWontUseSmallBufferOptimization)
```

Comment: I doubt trying to pull tricks like this is going to be worth it in real production code.

Comment: I'm kinda troubled `std::function` implementations won't do that of their own volition.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's defined as a copy-and-swap for exception safety

Comment: @Artyer - A potentially throwing constructor, for exception safety? Always cracks me up. This can still be constrained over noexcept constructibility.